# Trying to scrape Aliexpress

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape the price of a product on Aliexpress. I tried inspecting the element which looks like

```html
<span class="product-price-value" itemprop="price" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.detail.1000016.i3.fe3c2b54yAsLRn">US $14.43</span>
```

I'm trying to run the following code

'''

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32981494236.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.44ba26f6M32wxY&algo_pvid=520e41c9-ba26-4aa6-b382-4aa63d014b4b&algo_expid=520e41c9-ba26-4aa6-b382-4aa63d014b4b-22&btsid=0bb0623b16170222520893504e9ae8&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_'

source = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
soup.find('span', class_='product-price-value')
```

'''
but I keep getting a blank output. I must be doing something wrong but these methods seem to work in the tutorials I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what i got. As i understood right, the page what you gave, was recived by scripts, but in origin, it doesn't contain it, just script tags, so i just used split to get it. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005002281350811.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.42d53b59T5ddTM&algo_pvid=f3c72fef-c5ab-44b6-902c-d7d362bcf5a5&algo_expid=f3c72fef-c5ab-44b6-902c-d7d362bcf5a5-1&btsid=0b8b035c16170960366785062e33c0&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_&sku_id=12000019900010138'
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, features="lxml")
res = soup.findAll("script")
total_value = str(res[-3]).split("totalValue:")[1].split("}")[0].replace("\"", "").replace(".", "").strip()
print(total_value)
```

It works fine, i tried on few pages from Ali.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your tip on the script tag as well!